# Camera positioning speed in big scene

Tags: camera

I have a qestion about camera moving speed in huge scene. I changed scale of whole project down but with that it sized down camera movement. In ex at start with my world scale 1 when I change location of my camera (with navigation menu) by 1m, so I scaled whole world to 0.01 and now my camera is movin like 0.01m so its like whole scene doesnt change at all, is there any chance to change the step camera is moving?